# How can I connect to remote hive metastore which is kerberized using spark-shell from Google Cloud Platform ssh terminal?

Tags: hive, kerberos, spark-shell

I wanna read data from remote hive server in spark-shell and write in bigquery table. I am facing issue in establishing connection to hive metastore. I have downloaded krb5.conf and keytab file and using them spark-shell still not able to make connection due to kerberize issue. Can someone please tell me the right way to establish connection?

I followed this tutorial
https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/how-to-connect-spark-to-remote-hive/

It doesnt have kerberized hive metastore guide